# tikzpicture line origin too far right

Tags: margins, tikz-arrows

I'm attempting to make it so I can draw an arrow on a page.  I want it to start as far left as the page margin, but it seems like it's adding extra padding that's shoving it too far to the right.  I've fought with it for hours, but nothing seems to shove that to the left, short of changing the margin for the whole page (which is not desirable if I can avoid it).  Here's some basic code (the arrow is on page 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 7

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
ion
\tableofcontents
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{P-1}\markboth{P-1}{}
\begin{center}
\Huge
P-1
\end{center}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\label{page408964}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{AS 3043001.020 WHT MADERA ADA BOWL 1-1/2TS FLOOR MOUNT}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,red,ultra thick]\draw[-{Stealth[red,scale=1.3,angle'=45]},ultra thick] (0,0) -- (468pt,-647pt);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}...` ?

Comment: You ought not be formatting chapter and section headings manually. That way madness lies. Use `\chapter{}` or `\section{}` or `\chapter*{}` or `\section*{}` and customise their format globally, in your preamble, if necessary.

Comment: I'll see if I can tweak that portion of it.  The actual code is a fair amount more complex, so it may take a bit.  The noindent helps tremendously.  Is there a way to manually force it over even a bit more?  I'm OK if it requires the header/footer to be wider.

Comment: Add `showframe` to the options for `geometry`. Because you are manually making headings for some reason, you may be introducing spurious spacing. If you want it to ignore the page margins, you can do that: just tell TeX that the box you put the image in is 0pt wide. That is: lie. TeX is very trusting: it will believe anything you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of `\noindent` is sufficient to start the arrow from the north west corner of the text area, as this illustration demonstrates:

[image: no indentation]

If you move it further left, it will no longer be within the text area, but will begin in the left margin.

I've also tidied up your code a little, although not that much:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in, headheight=15pt, showframe]{geometry}% headheight=15pt is from fancyhdr -READ THE CONSOLE OUTPUT: it sometimes tells you things you NEED to know; showframe is just for testing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 7
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% better bookmarks, fewer compilations
% if you want to customise the format of chapters, sections etc. you can use titlesec
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
ion
\tableofcontents
\clearpage\markboth{}{}% clear the ToC header from headers/footers (\chapter won't do this if starred)
\chapter*{P-1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{P~1}% replace manual formatting of section headings and chapter titles!!
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\label{page408964}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{AS 3043001.020 WHT MADERA ADA BOWL 1-1/2TS FLOOR MOUNT}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,red,ultra thick]
  \draw[-{Stealth[red,scale=1.3,angle'=45]},ultra thick] (0,0) -- (468pt,-647pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```